# Water collecting on timber outbuilding ceiling (inside), possibly structure related, causing water damage (is the structure the cause?)

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing, water-damage

I have a problem with a timber outbuilding built this last summer. I'm wondering if the problem is related to the fact that I asked the contractor to omit the insulation and internal OSB skin (to save costs, as it's only being used as a workshop so does not need to be warm). The building has otherwise been built to the architects specification (drawings below).

The first picture below show the architects design. The roof structure as per the design (from top to bottom) includes the EPDM rubber roof on top of plywood followed by an air gap, then the insulation board and the internal OSB skin beneath that.

The second picture below that shows the air flow the design allows for.

What has been left out of the build for the time being, is the lower two layers, the insulation board and the lower internal OSB skin. As a result from the inside of the building the rafters and the top plywood layer are visible.

**The problem is that the building seems to be generally damp, and during recent snow and below freezing temperatures (we're in the South West UK) a significant amount of water (possibly ice before the thaw) collected on the ceiling (the ceiling currently being the top plywood layer directly beneath the outer EPDM roof).**

The wet ceiling is shown on the 3rd picture. What is not very clear from the picture is that there are water droplets forming at the boundary between sheets, along with discolouration from the damp. This photo of the ceiling is from above the level roof lights, so I do not expect that the problem is caused by the seal around the roof lights.

It's worth mentioning that the raised design of this outbuilding is because the ground beneath it becomes water logged during winter months.

It's not clear to me where the water is coming from. The buildings foundational supports have a damp proof layer. I can understand water condensation on a cold roof in the snow, but the amount was surprising, and the water dripping down from the ceiling has left large puddles on the floor in multiple areas. Shelves with tools on have mould growing on them (interestingly the shelves closer to the ground are less affected - the damp appears to be concentrated towards the top of the room).

My questions are:

- Have I possibly negated air flow that would keep the ceiling (and therefore the rest of the building) dry?
- Or, would the insulation and internal OSB skin simply have hidden the water?
- Where is the water coming from (assuming the roof is not leaking as it's fine with heavy rain. Is it flowing into the building with the air and then compensating on the ceiling)?
- Is there anything else that should be incorporated into the design to keep the interior of the building dry?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the inside heated somehow or just outside temp? The last photo seems to show water stains from  water coming in through the joint between panels. What is above that joint?

Comment: Looks like a number of skylights. Those may let in enough light/heat to warm the inside. The air inside would then absorb moisture and rise and hit the (cold?) roof sheathing, condensing there. Normally one puts a vapor barrier on the warm side of insulation so warm moist air does not get to a cold surface where condensation would form.

Comment: @Armand, above that joint is continuous EPDM rubber. The whole plywood sheets were wet to touch so the drips on the joints are just where it collects. The room is not heated, but you're right that it warms with sunlight through the roof lights. So do you think if I added the insulation and internal OSB skin that's been omitted it would solve the problem?

Comment: Also, why is it that a warmer interior would absorb water?

Comment: Warmer air can hold more water vapor.  It's like dew outside - during the day water evaporates into the warmer air, then at night as the air cools down some of that water vapor condenses out onto (especially) colder surfaces. The bigger the temperature change, the bigger the effect. Without insulation, the temp changes are certainly bigger, but I don't know enough to know if the original design would fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.